# ksh93 date calculation using builtin printf function

Tags: shell, date, printf, ksh

I need to do date calculations in a shell script. Unfortunately my operating system (SunOS) does not provide a very handy date function: **it does not support the -d option** which is exactly what I need.

Roaming on the web to find an alternate solution i found something that looks to be powerful enough with **ksh93 printf builtin function**. It supports syntaxes like that:

```
yesterday=${ printf "%(%Y%m%d)T" yesterday; }
friday=${ printf "%(%Y%m%d)T" "3 days ago"; }
```

In my case, i need to calculate **2 days before a calculated date**, in my understanding it should be written like that *(mydate is formatted as "YYYYMMDD")*:

```
dayinthepast=${ printf "%(%Y%m%d)T" "3 days before $mydate"; }
```

or

```
dayinthepast=${ printf "%(%Y%m%d)T" "$mydate - 3 days"; }
```

But it does not work.

The more surprising is that the second syntax is recognized but it takes the minus as a plus and add 3 days to the given date.

I have read a useful blog covering the ksh93 printf builtin syntax but it does not cover my case. I'm giving the link here (thanks for the author): [ksh93-date-manipulation](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2008/10/ksh93-date-manipulation.html)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `$mydate` is the content of the variable? Well, nothing you can do. If the tools you have do not support what you want, you have basically two options: roll your own solution - ie write in ksh (or in other language) a library that does what you want, or install new tools - download GNU coreutils or try with dateutils or other library that does what you want.

Comment: Actually i suspect ksh93 to support what i do, In the last example it does not crash, it does just react in a strange way. this demonstrates the syntax is almost supported. I think i just miss the proper way to code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me on AIX 7.1:

```
$ ksh93
$ MY_DATE=20210601
$ printf "%(%Y%m%d)T" "${MY_DATE} 3 days ago"
20210529
```

got the hint from the link - [ksh93-date-manipulation](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2008/10/ksh93-date-manipulation.html) - there's a paragraph there that mentions "23 days ago"